# Feasibility of Integration of custom MDF to EmployeeTimeSheetEntry via HCI

Tags: integration, hana, sap-business-technology-platform, sap-successfactors

I want to **leverage the functionality of Employee Central Time-Off** for showing punch-in & punch-out time of an employee. Is this possible to implement the mapping of punch-in and punch-out time fields from custom MDF say **`cust_Clock_time`** to the fields of **`EmployeeTimeSheetEntry`** via HCI?

In other words, it would be outbound integration of SF with HCI from MDF perspective but it would be inbound of SF with HCI from `EmployeeTimeSheetEntry`'s perspective.

**(1) Mapping Fields Sheet:**

[image]

**(2) IFLOW after running traces**

[image]

Comment: what exactly is your question? Sounds possible. I would recommend using the OData API to fill TimeSheet from HCI.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've understood, you would achieve this in a REAL EASY manner with SF Integration Center.

Source: SF, Target: SF, nice-and-easy WYSIWYG Mapping Editor...

[image]

Comment: Thanks @zyrex . I tried your suggestion..but it showing me the error that   **EmployeeTimeSheetEntry does not support operation UPSERT**.

Comment: Any suggestions to overcome the same?

Comment: First Go to odata dictionnary in your Tenant. Check your timesheet if it is updatable or creatable. If no request changing this to upsertable via implementation Partner . If yes you can Switch in Integration Center from upsert to create or Update (tab configure Fields –> Operation which is set to upsert by default)

Comment: Thanks @zyrex
When I check EmployeeTimeSheetEntry in Odata dictionary, they are not upsertable, updatable and creatable.

Comment: oh okay, I understood that you are able to switch this in provisioning. but there might be a reason for this. any idea?

Comment: you mean we can switch this setting of TimeSheetEntry from provisioning? Is it so? @zyrex

Comment: I Know that we switched from non-filterable to filterable. I think its worth trying for Create/Change. Maybe easiest is to ask sap also for consequences or why it is not possible.

Comment: No, SAP said it can't be done...May be in next 2019 updates they will provide the permissions for Create/Change/Upsert etc. for TimeSheet

Comment: anyway, accept the answer. this would be the way how it works. SAP limitations always have to be checked in advance. thank you.